# 分 in 今回は単行本第三巻予定分から

Tags: translation, words, suffixes

I'm trying to translate somebody's tweet, and I'm just blocking on this one bit. I understand every part ("単行本", "第三巻", "予定", "から"), except the "分", of course. I know what the kanji "分" means individually, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to designate in this sentence.

Here is the full sentence:

> 今回は単行本第三巻予定**分**から、第二話と第三話をまとめました

I can't quite get if it's supposed to mean basically "part of 単行本", or I've went as far as to exaggerate the translation and say "chapter" for it, because of "第二" and "第三". Maybe that's just a problem of sentence structure, and what part/word 分 is connected to, or maybe that's just an expression with から or 予定 (which in that case I'm not seeing, despite checking in dictionaries), in any case, I'm just really blocked on this one kanji and its meaning in the phrase.

Answer (score 9):

～分 (pronounced ぶん) means "a part/amount that corresponds to ～", "～'s fraction", etc. In this case, it refers to a part of the entire work (not a part of Volume 3 nor a part of one episode).

単行本第三巻予定分 is "the part (of the entire work) which is planned to be included in the third volume".

Other examples of 分:

- 追加分: the added part (as opposed to the original)
- 来月分: the task which needs to be done next month, the resource for the next month, etc.
- 1日分の食料: a day's worth of food