# Understanding 分?

Tags: word-usage

> 今週は大学のオリエンテーション。要は、これから一年受ける講義を選ぶための説明、及び体験期間である。自分の興味のある科目や必修科目を、進級・卒業に必要な単位の**分**、バランスよく選ばなければならない。

What is the function of the bold 分? Is it like 一年間の休職の分だけ、仕事がたまっていた。?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [分 in 今回は単行本第三巻予定分から](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30054/%e5%88%86-in-%e4%bb%8a%e5%9b%9e%e3%81%af%e5%8d%98%e8%a1%8c%e6%9c%ac%e7%ac%ac%e4%b8%89%e5%b7%bb%e4%ba%88%e5%ae%9a%e5%88%86%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89)

Comment: @naruto Hi. I don’t quite think it answered my question. I know that usage. If it were 単位分, I would have considered it was the same usage as the example in the link.

Comment: It's the same. That の after 単位 can be dropped, and you can add の and say 第3巻予定の分. 追加分 is the same as 追加の分 or 追加した分/追加する分, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

As commented, they mean the same [ある範囲の分量。区別されたもの。](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%88%86_%28%E3%81%B6%E3%82%93%29/#jn-197124).

A way to understand such 分 is to think about the amount of *what* is being talked about.

For the sentences in the question:

- 必要な単位の分**の科目や必修科目**
- 休職の分**の仕事**

A possible process to understand the sentece as follows:

The main clause is

- 自分の興味のある科目や必修科目を、バランスよく選ばなければならない。You have to choose (compulsory) courses interesting to you in a well balanced way.

The part ending in 分 describes how much those 科目や必修科目 should be:

- 進級や卒業に必要な単位の分 : the amount of courses you take is such that you can get credits required for successfully proceeding to next year/graduation

The second sentence can be understood in the same way:

- 仕事が溜まっていた : Tasks had been accumulating
- 一年間の休職の分 : the amount of those tasks is such that it represents a year's leave

I guess a difficulty lies in that you have to change the structure of the sentence a lot in order to get a decent translation (which I didn't do above).

===

I am wondering if there is no single English word for 進級.