# Is there rendaku with consecutive counters?

Tags: counters, rendaku

In this [Asahi article](https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASQ2871W8Q27POMB006.html?iref=pc_photo_gallery_breadcrumb) about a bicycle-powered knitting machine, the following sentence appeared:

> [1足分]{いっそくふん}を[編]{あ}むのに[10分]{じゅっぷん}[程度]{ていど}こぐという
>
> *It takes about 10 minutes of pedaling to knit one pair (of socks, he says).*

Is it [1足分]{いっそくふん} or [1足分]{いっそくっぷん}?

Comment: そくっぷん is impossible. If anything, it would be そっぷん like 六分 but we don't say that.

Comment: The first 分 is not a counter nor a unit in the first place; [it's a suffix](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30056/5010) that typically (but not always) follows a counter.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on rendaku notes several inconsistencies / complications / exceptions in the application of rendaku: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku

Comment: @SarahMesser Rendaku is actually not relevant in 一足分. As can be confirmed in any dictionary, ぶん is an inherently voiced on-reading of 分, and it's ぶん even after a verb or a particle (e.g., 彼にあげた分【ぶん】 "the portion I gave him", 明日の分【ぶん】 "tomorrow's portion"). This is similar to 地, which has both voiced and unvoiced on-readings (ち as in 地上 and じ as in 地震).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

いっそくぶん is correct.
分 for this meaning is always pronounced as "ぶん" like "じゅうねんぶん"(10年分), "ふつかぶん"(2日分).